# Yii - Highcharts - Cannot get chart to show

Tags: php, yii, highcharts

I'm using the Yii Highcharts extension, but cannot get a chart to draw. I *think* I can see what the issue is but can't figure out how to correct it. My Highchart widget code is:

```
$this->Widget('ext.highcharts.HighchartsWidget', array(
   'options'=>array(
        'chart' => array(
         'renderTo' => 'myContainer2',
         ),
  'title' => array('text' => 'title'),
  'xAxis' => array(
       'categories' => $gross_demand_by_date_date
  ),
  'yAxis' => array(
     'title' => array('text' => 'ytitle')
  ),
  'series' => array(
     array('name' => 'gross demand', 'data' => $data_array),
  )
   )
));
```

If I look in the source of the rendered page, the $data_array variable is shown as:

```
'data':'array(23920,19898,20326.....
```

But I think it should be:

```
'data':array(23920,19898,20326....
```

(i.e. no quote mark just before `array`).

I've played around with the `data_array` variable, having it as an array and as a string, but no joy.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you post `jsfiddle` with the browser output?

Comment: @Veseliq - thanks, but I don't think I can do that - at least don't know how to do it. I'm using the Yii Highcharts extension, so the call to Highcharts is different to the regular call. Here it is:  jQuery(window).on('load',function() {
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({'chart':{'renderTo':'myContainer2'},'exporting':{'enabled':true},'title':{'text':'Fruit Consumption'},'xAxis':{'categories':['20130502','20130503','20130504']},'yAxis':{'title':{'text':'Fruit eaten'}},'series':[{'name':'Jane','data':'array(23920,19898,20326)'}]});
});

Comment: can you please show us what is in the `$data_array`??

Answer (score 0):

I think you need another array in data:

```
 'series' => array (
            array (
              'type' => 'pie',
              'name' => 'Browser share',
              'data' => array (
               array('Firefox', 44.2),
               array('IE7', 26.6),
               array('IE6', 20),
               array('Chrome', 3.1),
               array('Other', 5.4)
            ),
        ),
```

Check this: [Highchart and yii not drawing a pie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302704/highchart-and-yii-not-drawing-a-pie/16302994#16302994)